# AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute '_validate_params'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, nlp, anaconda

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix,precision_score
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train,y_train)type here
```

I'm getting an AttributeError when I tried to train my model using Gaussian Naive Baiyes algorithm. I tried this with MultinomialNB and BernoulliNB also, but I'm recieving the same error.

This is the error message which I recieved.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[290], line 2
      1 #training Guassian Naive Bayes model
----> 2 gnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
      3 y_pred = mnb.predict(X_test)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py:265, in GaussianNB.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    242 def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
    243     """Fit Gaussian Naive Bayes according to X, y.
    244 
    245     Parameters
   (...)
    263         Returns the instance itself.
    264     """
--> 265     self._validate_params()
    266     y = self._validate_data(y=y)
    267     return self._partial_fit(
    268         X, y, np.unique(y), _refit=True, sample_weight=sample_weight
    269     )

AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute '_validate_params'
```

Kindly someone help me to solve this.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.